# Need to import 10 million of data from s3 bucket to postgres database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have 7Gb of file which have 10 million of data, to process that file we had created 100 MB chunks in s3 bucket and processing one by one file from s3 to insert records in 24 table along with rollbacking/commit transactions. It takes around more than one week to handle those data. Can anyone help me with another quick solution.

### What I tried

Created SP/Function and triggers but not able to figure out as Postgres have lot's of limitations and I have related tables with has many relations

Please note this is an example. I have lot's of file like this.

Comment: Sorry, but your issue is not clear. What does it mean "7Gb file which have 10 million of data"? What data? Process how? What has Postgres to do with s3 and this file?

Comment: Have you checked out [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). 7GB does really not sound like a lot? Why not try the tools your database provides to import such files? Which database are you even using? Please provide more details. What is the source database? What is the target database (RDS? Oracle? Postgres? MySQL? Aurora?).

Comment: I am using Postgres database

Comment: @Jens Nimisha is working on this issue and we are looking for the solution.

Comment: @jens We have txt file from MLS and we are storing that file in s3 with file stream. Now I want to read that file chunks and save records in database. we are using DB facade of Laravel Framework to save records however it's time consuming process.